# How to Prevent Duplicate Values From JList in Java Swing Application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

I am using Netbeans IDE. Is there any property available for preventing duplicates entries in JList.

Any advice (sample links) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `LinkedHashSet` to eliminate duplicate entries and maintain order of elements. You need to do it before creating the model for `JList`, and then feed the model from this newly created `LinkedHashSet`

This ListModel could do the trick:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class DistinctListModel<E> extends DefaultListModel<E> {
    public DistinctListModel(Collection<E> data) {
        for (E e: new LinkedHashSet<E>(data)) {
            addElement(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much Krzysztof Cichocki